# Cloning and insert, inserting more times than expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a styled element with the class 'item' that is hidden. Initially the page will only have one element with this class. I am simply using this hidden element as a model, that I can grab with jquery and insert it into a list every time the 'add item' button is clicked, with the correct item name in the inner text.

What I am trying to do is clone this hidden 'item' element and insert it right after where the **last** item element is located on the webpage. Show it, and change the inner text to whatever I need.

My current implementation does not clone / insert items as expected, though I believe it should, I am probably missing something.

My Markup

```
<div class="item" style="border:1px solid blue; padding:7px; display:none;">hello</div>
```

add item

My JavaScript

```
$(".addItem").click(function(){

   //clone hidden item element blueprint
   $('.item').eq(0).clone().insertAfter('.item:last-child');


   //Change inner text of element
   $('.item:last-child').text("apples").show();
});
```

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/XPVAs/

Comment: More code please. Preferably on jsfiddle

Comment: Is the hidden `.item` part of the same list as the visible ones? If it isn't then `'.item:last-child'` would match it as well as the last element in the list. Also, if you bind this handler more than once (if this code is duplicated) then the element would be inserted more than once. (As is, the [posted code works](http://jsfiddle.net/RWG9N/) -- we need more info to help)

Comment: @MHZ Your modified version doesn't work because there is no `'.item:last-child'`; since you put the `.addItem` below it, that is now the last child. [`:last-child`](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) matches all elements which are the last child of their parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you need `:last` selector, instead of `:last-child`:

```
$(".addItem").click(function(){

    //clone hidden item element blueprint
    $('.item').eq(0).clone().insertAfter('.item:last');


    //Change inner text of element
    $('.item:last').text("apples").show();
});
```

And here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XPVAs/3/

Comment: +1 Thank you, this seems to work well ins jsFiddle, and way better in my code as well. I am not exactly sure why, but in my case, when I actually apply it to my code it adds two item elements instead of one, for every click. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Basically, as jquery doc says http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/ `While :last matches only a single element, :last-child can match more than one: one for each parent.` So it looks like you have some structure which returns more than one element with :last-child selector

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$('.item:last-child').text("apples").show();
```

to

```
$('.item:last').text("apples").show();
```

read the following links carefully:

http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/last/